# Does the steamcommunity market block the client after multiple tries?

Tags: java, parsing, proxy, steam, skins

I'm making a program in Java to parse data from a webpage on the steam community market. I know that the steamcommunity market blocks connections for a period of time if the connection is accessing the market too many times in a certain period. Right now, my program access a webpage every 250 milliseconds, and it will do that 10 times before switching to another proxy. My problem is that I will still get http error 429 (too many requests) even if I switch proxies. I know that the proxy switching works because I access my ip from http://checkip.amazonaws.com and it will return the ip of the new proxy. Does the steamcommunity market block clients as well as connections? Is there a way around this?

Here is the code:

```
               switch(proxyInt){
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("default");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "104.238.131.206");
                        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "158.85.241.82");
                        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "45.63.85.44");
                        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
                        break;
                }

                URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
                BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
                String ip = ins.readLine();
                System.out.println(ip);

                URL url = new URL("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + skins[x].substring(46));
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String gun = in.readLine();

                skinsLowest[x] = moneyLowest(gun);
                skinsMedian[x] = moneyMedian(gun);
                skinsProfit[x] = skinsMedian[x] * .87 - skinsLowest[x];

                lowestPrices[x].setText(skinsLowest[x] + "");
                medianPrices[x].setText(skinsMedian[x] + "");
                String round = skinsProfit[x] + "";
                profitPrices[x].setText(round.substring(0, 5));

                System.out.println("Lowest: " + skinsLowest[x]);
                System.out.println("Median: " + skinsMedian[x]);

                repaint();

                if(x % 10 == 0 && x != 0)
                    proxyInt++;

                if(x == amount)
                    x = 0;
                else
                    x++;
```

Comment: You answered your question, in your question. What does the code you posted have to do with your question? What would using multiple threads achieve, more requests and more denials? Are you positive it accesses the webpage every 250 ms, I don't see any benchmarking in your code.

Comment: Its in a runnable interface that repeats itself after 250 ms. I reworded the question. You are right about the threads, I thought they might be able to trick the market into thinking there were multiple clients. Also when it gives me error 429 I can access the page via chrome without an error.